# What transaction fee and percentage is being charged?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm looking at an online service which I give it a dollar amount and it returns a transaction fee on top of that, I want to know what the maths is behind the transaction fee based off this data.

If I enter.. 
 - 1 it charges a total of 1.63
 - 100 dollars it charges a total
   of 102.40 
 - 45 dollars it charges a total 46.42

Any idea how to calculate how the differences are calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We will assume it is linear and can be expressed in the form of $y=mx+b$.

In this case, $\text{final charge}=m\times\text{initial amount}+\text{flat fee}$

You basically have a graph of three points and want to find the equation for the line that goes through them.

There are several methods to solve for m and b. You can look up how to solve a linear equation given two points.  In this case we can use the points $(1,1.63)$ and $(45,46.42)$ to get the equation and use the third point as a check to see if the equation is correct.

This gives the equation $$\text{final charge}\approx1.01795\times\text{initial amount}+0.61205$$